# JPanel tearing even though I double buffer?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, doublebuffered, tearing

EDIT: This is an SSCCE to demonstrate my problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Main {
    public static BufferedImage map, tileSand, tileSea;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        map = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        for(int x = 0; x < 50 ; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < 50 ; y++){
                boolean colour = Math.random() < 0.5;
                if (colour){
                    map.setRGB(x, y, -256);
                } else {
                    map.setRGB(x, y, -16776961);
                }
            }
        }
        tileSand = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = tileSand.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 32, 32);
        tileSea  = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g = tileSea.getGraphics();
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 32, 32);
        Island test = new Main.Island();
        test.start();
        long start, sleep;
        while(true) {
            start  = System.currentTimeMillis();
            test.getCanvas().requestFocus();
            test.getCanvas().repaint();
            sleep = 15-(System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleep > 0 ? sleep : 0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    static class Island implements Runnable {

        private Tile[][] tiles;
        private JFrame frame;
        private JPanel panel;
        private Thread logicThread;
        private boolean running = false;
        private boolean paused = false;
        private Image image;
        private Player player;

        public Island() {
            image = new BufferedImage(1027, 768, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            player = new Player();
            tiles = new Tile[map.getWidth()][map.getHeight()];
            int rgb;
            for(int x = 0; x < map.getWidth(); x++) {
                for(int y = 0; y < map.getHeight(); y++) {
                    rgb = map.getRGB(x, y);
                    switch (rgb) {
                        case -16776961: tiles[x][y] = new Tile("sea");
                                        break;
                        case -256:  tiles[x][y] = new Tile("sand");
                                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
            makeMap();
            makeFrame();
            addBindings();
            logicThread = new Thread(this);
        }

        public JPanel getCanvas() {
            return panel;
        }

        public void start() {
            running = true;
            paused = false;
            logicThread.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            long sleep, before;
            while(running){
                before = System.currentTimeMillis();
                player.move();
                try {
                    sleep = 15-(System.currentTimeMillis()-before);
                    Thread.sleep(sleep > 0 ? sleep : 0);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
                while(running && paused);
            }
            paused = false;
        }

        private void makeFrame() {
            frame = new JFrame("Island");
            panel = new JPanel(){
                @Override
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 1024, 768);
                    long xl, yl;
                    xl = player.getLocation().x-512;
                    yl = player.getLocation().y-384;
                    int x2, y2;
                    x2 = (int) Math.floor(xl / 32);
                    y2 = (int) Math.floor(yl / 32);
                    int xoffset, yoffset;
                    xoffset = (int) (xl % 32);
                    yoffset = (int) (yl % 32);
                    for(int x = x2; x < x2+40; x++) {
                        for(int y = y2; y < y2+40; y++) {
                            if (x < tiles.length && x > 0 && y < tiles[0].length && y > 0) {
                                g2d.drawImage(tiles[x][y].getContent(), (x-x2)*32 - xoffset, (y-y2)*32 - yoffset, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                }
            };
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
            panel.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        private void addBindings() {
            InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap();
            ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("Q"),"hold-sprint");
            actionMap.put("hold-sprint", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.sprint(true);
                }
            });
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released Q"),"release-sprint");
            actionMap.put("release-sprint", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.sprint(false);
                }
            });
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"),"hold-right");
            actionMap.put("hold-right", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.right(true);
                }
            });
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released RIGHT"),"release-right");
            actionMap.put("release-right", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.right(false);
                }
            });
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"),"hold-down");
            actionMap.put("hold-down", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.down(true);
                }
            });
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released DOWN"),"release-down");
            actionMap.put("release-down", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.down(false);
                }
            });
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"),"hold-left");
            actionMap.put("hold-left", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.left(true);
                }
            });
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released LEFT"),"release-left");
            actionMap.put("release-left", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.left(false);
                }
            });
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"),"hold-up");
            actionMap.put("hold-up", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.up(true);
                }
            });
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released UP"),"release-up");
            actionMap.put("release-up", new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    player.up(false);
                }
            });
        }

        private void makeMap() {
            for(int x = 0; x < tiles.length; x++) {
                for(int y = 0; y < tiles[0].length; y++) {
                    switch (tiles[x][y].getType()) {
                        case "sea": tiles[x][y].setContent(tileSea);
                                    break;
                        case "sand":    tiles[x][y].setContent(tileSand);
                                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    static class Player{
        private Point location;
        private int xspeed, yspeed;
        private boolean left, up, right, down, sprint;

        public Player() {
            location = new Point(0, 0);
            left = false;
            up = false;
            right = false;
            down = false;
            sprint = false;
            xspeed = yspeed = 0;
        }
        public void left(boolean state){
            left = state;
        }

        public void up(boolean state){
            up = state;
        }

        public void right(boolean state){
            right = state;
        }

        public void down(boolean state){
            down = state;
        }

        public void sprint(boolean state) {
            sprint = state;
        }

        public void move() {
            if (sprint) {
                if (left) {
                    if(xspeed>-10)
                        xspeed--;
                } if (right) {
                    if(xspeed<10)
                        xspeed++;
                } if (up) {
                    if(yspeed>-10)
                        yspeed--;
                } if (down) {
                    if(yspeed<10)
                        yspeed++;
                }
            } else {
                if (left) {
                    if(xspeed>-5)
                        xspeed--;
                } if (right) {
                    if(xspeed<5)
                        xspeed++;
                } if (up) {
                    if(yspeed>-5)
                        yspeed--;
                } if (down) {
                    if(yspeed<5)
                        yspeed++;
                }
            }
            if (!sprint) {
                if (xspeed > 5) {
                    xspeed--;
                } if (xspeed < -5) {
                    xspeed++;
                }   if (yspeed > 5) {
                    yspeed--;
                } if (yspeed < -5) {
                    yspeed++;
                }
            }
            if (!left && !right) {
                if (xspeed > 0) {
                    xspeed--;
                } if (xspeed < 0) {
                    xspeed++;
                }
            } if (!up && !down) {
                if (yspeed > 0) {
                    yspeed--;
                } if (yspeed < 0) {
                    yspeed++;
                }
            }
            location.x = location.x + xspeed;
            location.y = location.y + yspeed;
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }
    }

    static class Tile {
        private String type;
        private BufferedImage tile;

        public Tile(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setContent(BufferedImage newTile) {
            tile = newTile;
        }

        public BufferedImage getContent() {
            return tile;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a JPanel with a modified paintComponent method. In this method I draw the relevant tiles from a 2d array to the screen based on the player location. I draw all my tiles to a BufferedImage and then I apply it to the screen at the end of the paint method. In theory this should not create tearing as I am double buffering? Here is the appropriate code, image is just a BufferedImage with the dimensions of the screen:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        long xl, yl;
        xl = player.getLocation().x-512;
        yl = player.getLocation().y-384;
        int x2, y2;
        x2 = (int) Math.floor(xl / 32);
        y2 = (int) Math.floor(yl / 32);
        int xoffset, yoffset;
        xoffset = (int) (xl % 32);
        yoffset = (int) (yl % 32);
        for(int x = x2; x < x2+40; x++) {
            for(int y = y2; y < y2+40; y++) {
                if (x < tiles.length && x > 0 && y < tiles[0].length && y > 0) {
                    g2d.drawImage(tiles[x][y].getContent(), (x-x2)*32 - xoffset, (y-y2)*32 - yoffset, null);
                }
            }
        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
```

I think the tearing could possibly be caused by the player's location changing over the duration of the paint method causing the tiles not to match up, the faster the player goes the more obvious the effect is. However I get the players location at the start and store it in two longs, I was under the impression that longs are passed by value not reference so the player location should be constant whilst the method runs.

I am happy to provide more code :), and thanks in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Change `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {..` to `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g)..`

Comment: Just tested and I'm afraid that has no affect, I was under the impression that you only need to do that if you are drawing components from swing on the panel as well?

Another thing to add, I don't extend my class with JPanel, I Override the paintComponent after I initialize the JPanel in my constructor. Like this:
panel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ etc...

Comment: The call to `super` also clears the BG, draws borders etc. Basically, you can't go wrong if you use it.  *For better help sooner, post an SSCCE.*

Comment: I have now added what I believe to be an SSCCE, to see the issue just run it and use the arrow keys, possibly holding down q as well.

Comment: I have read the article. By the sounds of things I've done something wrong though, I stripped down my code to try and isolate the problem, I replaced my many tiles and large map image with simpler ones using dummy data as you suggest in your article. I did try adding the code to my question directly, however whenever I tried to post it would complain about indenting four spaces which I had done, also I don't have enough rep to upload images so I though it would be best to make a zip file and upload to dropbox. Sorry if I've done it incorrectly, I genuinely thought this is what you wanted.

Comment: I have added an SSCCE to demonstrate my problem, this should run on its own I think. To best see the problem look at one of the vertical edges of the map and use the arrow keys to move right to left repeatedly, holding q will help.

Comment: OK - after a slight tweak to make it compilable in a Java 6 SDK (`switch` on `String` - at bloody last..) I saw ..no tearing at all here, even in 'q'uick mode.  Could it be your hardware?

Comment: My laptop has nvidia optimus, an intel integrated card is used for most of the graphics and a high performance nvidia card for more intensive programs. I have just been trying to get my project to run on my nvidia card rather than the intel card but have been unsuccessful so far. I tried adding javaw.exe to always be ran on the nvidia card but it seems to have no effect. I am going to test it on a few other computers I have and see if it still tears.

Comment: OK, I've tried it on different computers and I can still see tearing, or what I think is tearing. Are you certain that you can't see any graphical issues of any kind?

Comment: This is really annoying me so I'm just going to switch over to c++ and SDL before it's to late haha. I suppose it will be more suitable anyway :), thanks for taking the time to look at my code still though!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just so if people find my question and wonder what I ended up doing to "fix" it, switch over to c++ and SDL or some other image library before you are to far into your project, it's simply better for this kind of thing.

Comment: Why would you down vote my answer? it's the only solution I could find.